# Keeping complex eclipse installations in source control

Tags: eclipse

Do you see any problem with storing eclipse installations in source control?  Getting all the plugins installed for eclipse can be a bear and breaking one's installation is rather rough.  I've kept pre-configured zips before but keeping them up to date is a bit of a chore.

I think I can add eclipse + installed plugins to source control and then have my team checkout eclipse.  We can update and roll back using source control (broadcast changes to the user community).  We could also use it to debug what's different from known good when debugging eclipse launch failures.

Has anyone tried this or run into problems with this kind of approach?

Thanks

Peter